# Override excel formula

Tags: excel

I have a complex formula within my spreadsheet using the IF function with 3 variables. I now want the option to over ride this whole formula if cell (B1) equals 'MS'.

So, if B1='MS' I want the rule to be ignored and add 1908 to value in (A2) and calculated in cell A3.

The rule I am working with is:
A3 =IF(A1="FF",A2-100,IF(A1="SD",A2+50,IF(A1="REV",A2,"")))

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You could just wrap the current formula in another `if` condition:

```
=IF(B1='MS',
    A2+1908,
    IF(A1="FF", A2-100,IF(A1="SD",A2+50,IF(A1="REV",A2,""))))
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, will this override the original formula though? for example A1 could still equal FF and this needs to be ignored @timbiegeleisen

Comment: @ToniCarter If `B1` is `'MS'`, then your previous logic will be ignored, even if `A1` is `'FF'`.